# Replace whitespaces with dashes for each item in a list -python

Tags: python, whitespace, replace

Is there a way of simplifying this loop where i replaces whitespace with dashes for each item in a list?

```
for item in a_list:
    alist[alist.index(item)] = '-'.join(item.split(" "))
```

or is this better?

```
for item in a_list:
    alist[alist.index(item)] = item.replace(" ", "-")
```

**NOTE: The above solution only updates the 1st occurrence in this list, as David suggested, use *list comprehension* to do the above task.**

I have a list of words and some have dashes while some doesn't. The items in a_list looks like this:

```
this-item has a-dash
this has dashes
this should-have-more dashes
this foo
doesnt bar
foo
bar
```

The output should look like this, where all items in list should have dashes instead of whitespace:

```
this-item-has-a-dash
this-has-dashes
this-should-have-more-dashes
this-foo
doesnt-bar
foo
bar
```

Comment: both of your solutions won't work if you have duplicate items in your list since `.index` returns the first index of an item.

Comment: noted jamylak, david's list comprehension solution is the pythonic way to manipulate a list

Comment: Even though using a list comprehension is more Python, and usually simpler, and more flexible, it's still worth understanding how you can manipulate a list in-place without the `index` problems, because at some point that will come up.

Comment: @jamylak: Actually, in this case `index` would work. Once the first of multiple duplicates has been changed once, later duplicates won't try to replace it (or more precisely, if they *do* try to replace it, it means the duplicate string never had any spaces in it). So this is a rare case where `index` would work (although it is still not the best solution!!)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Aah i see you are correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [e.replace(" ", "-") for e in a_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself using the `index` method, you've probably done something wrong. (Not *always*, but often enough that you should think about it.)

In this case, you're iterating a list in order, and you want to know the index of the current element. Looking it up repeatedly is slow (it makes an O(N) algorithm O(N^3))—but, more importantly, it's fragile. For example, if you have two identical items, index will never find the second one.

This is exactly what `enumerate` was created for. So, do this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(a_list):
    alist[i] = '-'.join(item.split(" "))
```

Meanwhile, you could replace the loop with a list comprehension:

```
a_list = ['-'.join(item.split(" ")) for item in a_list]
```

This could be slower or use more memory (because you're copying the list rather than modifying it in-place), but that almost certainly doesn't matter (it certainly won't be as slow as your original code), and immutable algorithms are simpler and easier to reason about—and more flexible; you can call this version with a tuple, or an arbitrary iterable, not just a list.

As another improvement, do you really need to `split` and then `join`, or can you just use `replace`?

```
a_list = [item.replace(" ", "-") for item in a_list]
```

You could use regular expressions instead, which might be better for performance or readability in some similar cases—but I think in this case it would actually be worse. So, once you get here, you're done.